# Use of Undefined Constant Demolays - Assumed [Laravel Error]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I got an error in laravel, but idk if is on controller or blade file.

Controller Code:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $demolays = tbl_demolay::find($id);
    return view('demolay.edit', compact(demolays));
}
```

Blade Code:

---

```
{!! Form::model(['method' => 'PATCH','route' => ['demolay.update', $demolays->id]]) !!}
@include('demolay.form')
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because you need to pass string to the `compact()`. So, change it to:

```
return view('demolay.edit', compact('demolays'));
```